# Web API to upload images with c# (code behind)

Tags: c#, ajax, api, file-upload

I need the **c# code** to upload images to my web api. (*c# code that will do the same as my ajax call below*)

Here is **my working example** that I use to upload images from my web project via ajax call.

**HTML**

```
<form>
<span>Select file(s) to upload :</span>
<input id="file1" name="file1" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**ajax Call**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function (evt) {

        var files = $("#file1").get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            var data = new FormData();
            for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                data.append("file" + i, files[i]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.apiuri + "/api/book/UploadCover()",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (messages) {
                    for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                        $.smkAlert({ text: messages[i], type: 'success' });                            
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    $.smkAlert({ text: "Error while invoking the Web API", type: 'success' });                        
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**API Code in c#**

```
public async Task<List<string>> UploadCover()
{
    try
    {
        List<string> messages = new List<string>();

        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            string path = string.Format(@"C:\");

            API.Classes.ImageUploads.MyStreamProvider streamProvider = new API.Classes.ImageUploads.MyStreamProvider(path);

            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);


            foreach (var file in streamProvider.FileData)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
                try
                { 
                    messages.Add("<b>Book Cover Uploaded</b>");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    messages.Add("<b>Upload Failed</b>");
                }                        
            }

            return messages;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Request!");
            throw new HttpResponseException(response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Request Failed!");
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
}
```

Please help me with c# code to upload images to my web api. Thank you

Comment: Read about `HttpClient` or `WebClient` or any third-party library for working with HTTP as a client.

Comment: Code example does not look complete. Where does Request come from?

Comment: The code supplied is a working example that I am currently using successfully. What I am looking for is pure c# code that will do the same as the code under the 'ajax' section. The user must select image file(s) and click upload ... then the API section needs to process it async.